# Get "Current Node: [#document: null], type: 9" when call XMLSignature.validate and run on JBOSS 7

Tags: java, xml, jboss, xml-signature

I have a signed xml file with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?><ObjectMessage TXDATE="" TXNUM="" TXTIME="" TLID="" MBID="" LOCAL="N" MSGTYPE="O" OBJNAME="SA.SYSVAR" ACTIONFLAG="INQUIRY" CMDINQUIRY=" SELECT MAX(NVL(ACTUALVERSION,'')) AS ACTUALVERSION, MAX(NVL(AUTOUPDATE,'')) AS AUTOUPDATE, MAX(NVL(REPORTVERSION,'')) AS REPORTVERSION FROM (  SELECT VARVALUE AS ACTUALVERSION, '' AS AUTOUPDATE, '' REPORTVERSION FROM  SYSVAR WHERE VARNAME='ACTUALVERSION' UNION ALL SELECT '' AS ACTUALVERSION, VARVALUE AUTOUPDATE, '' REPORTVERSION  FROM  SYSVAR WHERE VARNAME='AUTOUPDATE' UNION ALL SELECT '' AS ACTUALVERSION, '' AUTOUPDATE, VARVALUE REPORTVERSION  FROM  SYSVAR WHERE VARNAME='REPORTVERSION')" CLAUSE="" FUNCTIONNAME="" AUTOID="" REFERENCE="" RESERVER="" IPADDRESS="192.168.22.22" CMDTYPE="T" PARENTOBJNAME="" PARENTCLAUSE="" SESSIONID="1A7FD51AB9F1989132EBEA49A3AF8F408AE906E35B84B7ED360F6CECC546EC6412674C14C693108735A9B8B0882261A9C44711AF60C343701D5BA1A6B5FCF2E40AB7858023C446E4B40CD0DFCE659032C083D3E5FA85504AF433F736BC39BD1A87D047430BF37B7B8D0EB960868A6C2C" REQUESTID="a341acd6-3540-48a0-9f92-b8e896bb1b50" CHILDTABLE=""><Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" /><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" /><Reference URI=""><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116"><XPath>ancestor-or-self::Signature</XPath></Transform></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" /><DigestValue>2jmj7l5rSw0yVb/vlWAYkK/YBwk=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>dz/JLG9rh+o5eAe34R4WQOBR/a+YJ3LCnSe6Uijh3bbwbXM6JvfLhux4T4DUJA+jb7UZoFWQ0orh7xAyh1ecWlyvrDSNrkWA3XjNuXLyxlNLOhOZIo4ou0glpLHGQHIC7u5q7OxLfBartbnnyZHvVrueFfwJvrZI4JkNqhwUll8=</SignatureValue><KeyInfo><X509Data><X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate></X509Data></KeyInfo></Signature></ObjectMessage>
```

I try to verify it with java code:

```
    File fff = new File("S:\\signeData.xml");
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fff);

    long byteLength = fff.length();

    byte[] filecontent = new byte[(int) byteLength];
    fileInputStream.read(filecontent, 0, (int) byteLength);
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
    Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder()
            .parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(filecontent));

    dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(XMLSignature.XMLNS,
                "Signature");

   String providerName = System.getProperty("jsr105Provider",
                "org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI");

   XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM",
                (Provider) Class.forName(providerName).newInstance());

   DOMValidateContext valContext = new DOMValidateContext(
                new XmlUtil.X509KeySelector(), nl.item(nl.getLength() - 1));
   XMLSignature signature = fac.unmarshalXMLSignature(valContext);
   res = signature.validate(valContext);
```

Almost another xml files can be authenticated, except for this file. It was crash in `res=signature.validate(valContext)` with `Current Node: [#document: null], type: 9` message. The puzzling point is, if I run this code on eclipse, everything is normal, the file is successfully validated. This error only occurs when the code is run on JBOSS 7, only with this file.

Comment: I'd guess that theres something slightly wrong with this file compared to the others that causing an XML parser exception.  If it runs fine in eclipse, what XML parser library are you using?  I'd make sure its being bundled with your application on deployment, if it is bundled and you're still getting the error, then you may need to try and exclude the Jboss XML parser and have it use your's instead using the jboss deployment descriptor file.